# Insert button if ListFragment doesn't contain any data

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listfragment

This is probably really simple. I have a ListFragment which gets populated with data from database. If there is no data inside database list is of course empty. Now I would like to show Button in the middle of the screen with a message that list is empty and data should be downloaded. How can I accomplish that with ListFragment?

I would check if list is empty like this:

```
if(getListAdapter().isEmpty())
{
    ... 
}
```

And then I somehow need to insert Button in the middle of the screen.

Thank you for suggestions!

Comment: you can't just put a invisible button and show it if is empty?

Comment: Where should I put it? I don't have defined layout for ListFragment.